# Set-PnPGroup : Group cannot be found

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Goal is to create a site collection level SharePoint group with 'Read' permissions, and apply this group to each sub-site.  This group should contain several members.

My code is failing on:

```
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $glbMGRConts -Owner $OwnersGroup
```

... and says Group cannot be found.  Not sure why, the group exists, and this line to set permissions to 'Read' works:

```
 Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $glbMGRConts -AddRole "Read"
```

#

```
$varURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL -UseWebLogin
#Grab global owners group
$OwnersGroup = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup

#Create name for group
$glbMGRConts = "GlobalMGRs"
New-PnPGroup -Title $glbMGRConts

Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName user1@co.com -Identity $glbMGRConts
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName user2@co.com -Identity $glbMGRConts

Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $glbMGRConts -AddRole "Read"
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $glbMGRConts -Owner $OwnersGroup

Function Get-Subsites() {  
    $subwebs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse   
     foreach ($Subweb in $subwebs)  
    {  
       Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $glbMGRConts -web $Subweb -AddRole Read
    }  
}   
Get-SubSites
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested below script in my environment.

```
$varURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $varURL -UseWebLogin
#Grab global owners group
$OwnersGroup = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup

#Create name for group
$glbMGRConts = "GlobalMGRs"
New-PnPGroup -Title $glbMGRConts

Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -Identity $glbMGRConts
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName user2@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -Identity $glbMGRConts

Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $glbMGRConts -AddRole "Read"
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $glbMGRConts -Owner $OwnersGroup.Title
Write-Host "---"
```

Comment: wow...so it was just basically use:
-Owner $OwnersGroup.Title

...needed "Title" property

Thank you!